# WebSocket connection failed - Angular

Tags: angular, websocket

I'm trying to use webSocket as seen in [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket), but I'm getting an error as I try to subscribe for it.

I'm new to webSockets - here is my code at app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket } from "rxjs/webSocket";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(){
        const subject = webSocket("ws://localhost:8081");
        subject.subscribe(
           msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg), // Called whenever there is a message from the server.
           err => console.log(err), // Called if at any point WebSocket API signals some kind of error.
           () => console.log('complete') // Called when connection is closed (for whatever reason).
        );
    }
}
```

And i'm getting this error on console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/' failed:
```

Why am I getting this error and subscription doesn't work?

Comment: seems there  is no websocket server listening on localhost:8081

Comment: You are right. Is there an easy way to create such a server just for learning purposes?

Comment: Yes, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws